# Asus windows 10 performance very slowly laptop and browsing very slowly

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, performance, asus-laptop

I'm using windows10 asus laptop i fed of this if i opened any software... it takes time to opened 2 min i'm getting angry with this..

i cleared browsing history caches and all but it will happen  again ... can any one please help i'l appreciated them

My specs: - Laptop: Hard disk 4GB

Windows recently installed the creators update for my laptop. Since that happend, my laptops' performance was very poor. Microsoft and nVidia both have a running case on this.

Comment: Maybe it's time you bought a better laptop? Seriously, give us a more specific spec list too work with. We don't even know your usage patterns, so we can't tell you why it might be slow. Try to upgrade your RAM to 8GB and replace your HDD with a SSD.

Comment: Check the processes running in task manager. and post complete config in the question.

Comment: I checked alreay

Comment: What does it say? Is you CPU utilization close to 100% when starting software? What about your browser? Is it using too much RAM?

Comment: @Kondal. There are lots of Questions You have to be clear. what software you are running what is usage of the CPU showing. Does this happens all software you run. Which CPU you are using with Speed?

Comment: Intel inside COREi3